# How do I fit a table in one page?

Tags: tables, formatting, supertabular, adjustwidth

I have very basic knowledge of LaTeX and I have been using LibreOffice's Word2LaTeX conversion software to convert my tables. However, I cannot seem to fit the tables into one page when I put the code into Scientific Wordplace. It always takes two. Is there anyway I can put it in one?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in} 
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{0.7874in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0.7874in}
\setlength\textheight{9.4251995in}
\setlength\textwidth{6.9251995in}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.0469in}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.0071in}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.0071in}}\vspace*{0.0398in}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
\renewcommand\@oddhead{}
\renewcommand\@evenhead{}
\renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
\renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}


\bigskip

{\color{black}
\foreignlanguage{english}{\textbf{Table A2: }}\foreignlanguage{english}{List    of countries included in the estimations
(by legal origin)}~ \foreignlanguage{english}{\textbf{[R2]}}}

\begin{flushleft}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}    {m{1.3275598in}m{0.7858598in}m{1.5775598in}m{0.7233598in}m{1.2858598in}m{0.7858598in}}
.
.
.
.
.

\end{supertabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    {\color{black}
    ~\textit{Notes}: The estimations include up to 78 countries listed in the table above. Figures in the table indicate
statehood experience accumulated over the period 1-1800 AD.}


\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be very helpful if you could remove all unnecessary lines in your code example.

Comment: Why does your code contains lots of `\color{black}` statements?

Comment: @Mico I know this problem in connection with those Word2LaTeX converters. Probably this is the reason.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is about. The code you've posted above does fit inside a page -- even though it's slightly wider than the textblock. So there must be some code you aren't showing that's causing the page break. Incidentally, a `supertabular` environment is designed to *allow* pagebreaks. If you don't want to allow pagebreaks, don't use a `supertabular` environment.

Comment: More about my assertion that the table is (slightly) too wide: Summing the widths of the 6 columns (`6.4851in`) and adding `12\tabcolsep` (`0.4724in`) , one gets `6.9585in` as the total width of the table. However, the width of the textblock has been set to `6.9252in`. (I've rounded all numbers to 4 digits after the decimal marker.) You need to change some of the column widths if you wish to make the tabular matter fit inside the textblock.

Comment: @Mico I just generated the code using the Word2LaTeX convertor as i need to put it into Scientific Workplace. If I open the tex in texmaker it fits into a page but when i open it in scientific workplace it doesnt fit into it.

Comment: The reason your table fits if you open the document as a standalone LaTeX document in TeXmaker, but not if you open the document in Scientific Workplace, is -- quite likely -- that Scientific Workplace is using different page dimension. To verify this conjecture, save your SWP document as a "portable LaTeX" document, open the resulting .tex file in TeXmaker, and recompile.

Comment: @mico aah that makes sense. Thanks I will try that. They should seriously consider teaching this stuff in grad school. :/

Comment: @tish - The sooner you wean yourself off SWP and get used to "straight LaTeX", the better off you'll be. Really. Also, don't rely too much on Word2LaTeX, especially not for table-related content. The conversion code you posted should, in my view, be classified as being somewhere between hair-raising and atrocious.

Comment: @Mico I have realised that about word2latex as well. Is there any other way to convert word tables to latex while I am still learning to code in latex?

Comment: Another option, if your table is only a bit too wide is to wrap it in an `adjustbox`. That allows resizing
@tish I use the VBA macro [Excel2Latex](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX), it produces normal table code

Comment: @tish Some of us DO teach this stuff to people in grad school.

Answer (score 6):

When setting up tables in a LaTeX document, it's crucial to engage in no, or only very little visual, formatting. Please study the following code and draw some inferences for how to go about encoding tabular material the LaTeX way.

For sure, if you don't want to allow a page break in the middle of the tabular material, don't employ an environment, such as `supertabular`, which is designed to allow pagebreaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.925in,textheight=9.425in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]                        % place the table on a page by itself
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\renewcommand\thetable{A\arabic{table}} % just for this example
\setcounter{table}{1}                   % just for this example

\caption{List of countries included in the estimations (by legal origin) \textbf{[R2]}}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.32756in}C{0.78in}p{1.57756in}C{0.78in}p{1.28586in}C{0.78in}@{}}
\toprule
Common Law LO & avg = 0.243 & Armenia    & 0.561   & Senegal & 0.448 \\
Australia     & 0.000       & Azerbaijan & 0.462   &         &       \\
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\textit{Notes}: The estimations include up to 78 countries listed in the table above. Figures in the table indicate
statehood experience accumulated over the period 1--1800 AD.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer to your other question, which you deleted as I was about to post it. While I assume you don't want an answer now, having put the effort it, I hope it may be of use to somebody. In essence, the question is sufficiently similar to this one that it seems legitimate to post it here. If not, I can delete it later when I'm less aware of having just spent time on something no longer wanted.

---

The code does not give an error but it come more closely approximate to recognised best practice.

Consider the following rewrite, but note that I'm not entirely clear what represents what e.g. what is really a maths variable and what text. Also, if these are statistics, you should probably be using `siunitx`.

Key points:

1. A `table` is a *float*. It is designed to move automatically somewhere else. Hence, anything crucial to that table needs to be *in* the float: caption, notes, whatever.
2. Never number enumerated things. Always let TeX keep count for you: items in lists, tables, figures, sections, references, pages, equations, paragraphs. Whatever it is, if it needs numbering, get TeX to count. TeX won't mind re-counting when you decide to add a second item after finishing the 404th, and it won't forget to change the numbers if you move the third figure after the fifth.
3. Use `booktabs` for rules.
4. Use `caption` for help formatting captions.
5. `\label{<key>}` in a `table` is useless unless a `\caption` precedes it. There is nothing for it to refer to if you've written `Table 1` rather than `\caption{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  % everything that must remain with the table needs to go in the table environment, because it may move
  % use \caption to create the caption - never hard-code numbered items
  \caption{Descriptive statistics and correlation coefficients of key variables}\label{tab:tab1}
  % it's a switch - personally, I think it is better to use it as one
  \scriptsize
  % don't add extra vertical space with the center environment
  {% limit the effect with a group
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lccccC}% make the tabular as wide as the line, using all the available space in the last column, which is the only multiline one anyway

      \toprule
      Variable &
      Mean&
      Std. Dev.&
      Min.&
      Max.&
      Correlation coefficient with $FinDev$\\
      \midrule
%       $State\, x\, German\, LO$ & % should this really all be presented as maths variables?
      State $x$ German $LO$ &
      0.086&
      0.224&
      0&
      0.938&
      0.24 \\

%       $State\, x\, Scandinavian\, LO$ & % ditto
      State $x$ Scandinavian $LO$ & % ditto
      0.019&
      0.105&
      0&
      0.771&
      0.30 \\
      \bottomrule

    \end{tabularx}

  }% end of centring
  \smallskip

  % if the notes should stay with the table, they need to be in the table
  \emph{Notes}: The descriptive statistics provided in the table include the 127 countries used in the baseline regressions.
  Sources and definition of data are described in the text and Appendix 1.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: reformatted table]

Comment: +1. Two minor points: Since the width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`, `\centering` has no effect and amy be omitted; and, the funky `$x$` particles must surely be `$\times$`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I actually included the `\centering` just to show how to avoid the use of `center`, which was used in the original code. However, you're right that I could have omitted it here. I didn't originally use `tabularx` but ended up there later. (You are possibly also right about the `x`s. I really don't know what is supposed to be maths and what not, since originally all of it was maths.)